# The "tree property" and dividing types

Tags: logic, model-theory

Recall that a family of formulas $\{\varphi_i(v)\}_{i\in I}$ is said to be "$k$-inconsistent" if every conjunction of $k$ distinct members of the family is inconsistent. We say that an $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\varphi(v,w)$ has the "tree property" for $k$ if there is a collection of parameters $\{b_s:\emptyset\neq s\in\omega^{<\omega}\}$, where $\omega^{<\omega}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega^n$, such that (a) $\{\varphi(v,b_{si})\}_{i\in\omega}$ is $k$-inconsistent for every $s\in\omega^{<\omega}$, and (b) $\{\varphi(v,b_s):\emptyset\neq s\subseteq\sigma\}$ is consistent for every $\sigma\in\omega^\omega$. In other words, the children of every node of the tree are $k$-inconsistent, and every path through the tree cuts out a consistent family of formulas. A theory $T$ is simple if there is no formula with the tree property, modulo $T$.

I'm having a bit of trouble with proposition 7.2.5. in Tent and Ziegler, which proves that $T$ is simple if and only if there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that, for all models $M$ and all $p\in S_n(M)$, there is some $X\subseteq M$, of size $\leqslant\kappa$, such that $p$ does not divide over $X$. I'm having trouble in particular with their proof of the backwards direction; I've copied it verbatim below. We work in a monster model $\mathfrak{C}$.

> If $\varphi(v,w)$ has the tree property, there are $\varphi$-$k$ dividing sequences $(\varphi(v,b_\alpha))_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$. It is easy to construct an ascending sequence of models $(M_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$ such that each $\varphi(v,b_\alpha)$ divides over $M_\alpha$ and such that $b_\beta\in M_\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$. Extend the collection $\{\varphi(v,b_\alpha)\}_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$ to a type $p(v)\in S(M)$, where $M=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa^+}M_\alpha$. Then $p$ divides over each $M_\alpha$.

(A "$\varphi$-$k$" dividing sequence over $X$, of length $\lambda$, is a consistent family $(\varphi(v,b_\alpha))_{\alpha<\lambda}$ such that each $\varphi(v,b_\alpha)$ divides over $X\cup\{b_\beta\}_{\beta<\alpha}$ with respect to $k$. Tent and Ziegler have proved that every formula with the tree property for $k$ has a $\varphi$-$k$ dividing sequence over any parameter set, of any length.)

---

Unfortunately the construction of the models is unclear to me. We seem to have two choices; the naive approach is to choose a single dividing sequence $(\varphi(v,b_\alpha))_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$ at the onset, say over $\emptyset$, and then try to construct the desired models with this dividing sequence fixed. I run into problems with this approach, however. Constructing $M_0$ is fine; we can use, eg, exercise 7.1.1. of Tent and Ziegler to find a model $M_0$ such that $\varphi(v,b_0)$ divides over $M_0$. (This is just an application of the "standard lemma" on indiscernible sequences.) However, I struggle with the higher stages:

For simplicity, I focus on constructing $M_1$, which is representative of the problem I'm having in the general case too. We know that $\varphi(v,b_1)$ divides over $b_0$, and that $\varphi(v,b_0)$ divides over $M_0$. If we could show that $\varphi(v,b_1)$ divides over $\{b_0\}\cup M_0$, we would then be done; we could find $\mathcal{I}$ an $M_0\cup\{b_0\}$-indiscernible sequence such that $b_1\in\mathcal{I}$ and $(\varphi(v,b))_{b\in\mathcal{I}}$ is $k$-inconsistent, and then use (the argument of) exercise 7.1.1. to find a model $M_1\succeq M_0$ such that $b_1\in M_1$ and such that $\mathcal{I}$ remains indiscernible over $M_1$. Then $\varphi(v,b_1)$ would divide over $M_1$, witnessed by $\mathcal{I}$, as desired. However, I'm not convinced that $\varphi(v,b_1)$ will divide over $\{b_0\}\cup M_0$ in general... to show such a thing, we'd want to use a sort of transitivity property of the following shape:

> If $\varphi(v,b)$ divides over $\{a\}$, and $\varphi(v,a)$ divides over $X$, then $\varphi(v,b)$ divides over $X\cup\{a\}$. (Subject to some appropriate conditions on $X$, $a$, and $b$, eg that $\varphi(v,a)\wedge\varphi(v,b)$ is consistent.)

However, this is of different form than all the transitivity properties of dividing that we've proved so far; for instance, in exercise 7.1.7. we showed that

> If $\operatorname{tp}(a/X\cup\{b\})$ does not divide over $X$, and $\varphi(v,b)$ divides over $X$, then $\varphi(v,b)$ divides over $X\cup\{a\}$.

Most transitivity properties have been of this form, obtaining a conclusion of dividing with one hypothesis of dividing and one hypothesis of non-dividing. As far as I can tell, this is of fundamentally different shape than obtaining a conclusion of dividing from *two* hypotheses of dividing, so I'm not even convinced the desired result is true. (My attempts to prove it, even in the specific case above, have not led anywhere, although I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample either.)

---

So, this approach doesn't appear fruitful to me. The second approach is to construct not only the models but also the *parameters* $(b_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$ inductively. However, we seem to run into a different problem here; in this approach, for the rest of Tent and Ziegler's argument to work, we need to ensure that $\varphi(v,b_\alpha)$ is consistent with $\{\varphi(v,b_\beta)\}_{\beta<\alpha}$ at each stage, and I don't see how to do this. For simplicity, again suppose that we have constructed $M_0$ and $b_0$ as above and are trying to construct $M_1$ and $b_1$. We can find a $\varphi$-$k$ dividing sequence over $M_0\cup\{b_0\}$; call it $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$. Unfortunately, this alone is of no help, since there is no guarantee that $\{\varphi(v,b_0),\varphi(v,a_\gamma)\}$ is consistent, for any $\gamma$.

---

So I'm at a bit of a loss. Tent and Ziegler do say this construction should be easy, so I'm wondering if I'm overthinking something or missing something obvious; any insight (or hints!) would be appreciated. Once we've actually constructed the models, then I don't have any trouble with finishing the argument. Indeed, if $X\subseteq M$ is such that $|X|\leqslant \kappa$, then for each $x\in X$ let $\alpha(x)$ be minimal such that $x\in M_{\alpha(x)}$. Then $\gamma:=\bigcup_{x\in X}\alpha(x)$ is a union of $\leqslant\kappa$ sets, each of cardinality $\leqslant\kappa$, so $\gamma<\kappa^+$. Then we have $X\subseteq M_\gamma$, and so, since $p\ni\varphi(v,b_\gamma)$ divides over $M_\gamma$, it divides over $X$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, the statement you want to prove is:

> If $T$ has the tree property, then for every cardinal $\kappa$, there is model $M$ and a type $p\in S(M)$ such that for all $X\subseteq M$ with $|X|\leq \kappa$, $p$ divides over $X$.

Note that if we drop the condition that $M$ is a model, the proof is easy,  given  that we know that the  tree property gives rise to dividing sequences. If $\varphi(x,y)$ has the tree property, then there is a $\varphi$-$k$-dividing sequence $(\varphi(x,b_\alpha))_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$. Let $B = \{b_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa^+\}$. By the definition of dividing sequence, $\{\varphi(x,b_\alpha)\mid \alpha<\kappa^+\}$ is consistent, so we can take $p\in S(B)$ to be any completion of this partial type. Now for any $X\subseteq B$ with $|X|\leq \kappa$, since $\kappa^+$ is regular there is some $\beta<\kappa^+$ such that $X\subseteq B_\beta = \{b_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\}$. By the definition of dividing sequence, $\varphi(x,b_\beta)\in p$ divides over $B_\beta$, and hence over $X$, so $p$ divides over $X$.

---

Now we want to "upgrade" $B$ to a model. There's a standard  trick for turning behavior over arbitrary sets into behavior over models: Skolemization.  It's entirely possible that there's a straightforward way to carry out the proof in T&Z  without Skolemizing, but I agree with you that it's not obvious.

Let $\mathfrak{C}^+$ be an expansion of the monster model $\mathfrak{C}$ by Skolem functions, let $L^+$ be the expanded language, and let $T^+$ be $\mathrm{Th}_{L^+}(\mathfrak{C}^+)$. Then $T^+$ has the tree property, witnessed by the same $L$-formula $\varphi(x;y)$ and the same tree.

[Aside: This is one of the benefits of the tree property characterization of (non)-simplicity - it is "purely local" in the sense that it only depends on the behavior of a single formula $\varphi(x,y)$, so it is preserved under expansions and reducts which contain $\varphi$. Notice that, in contrast, it is not obvious that the existence of a $\varphi$-$k$-dividing chain is preserved under expansion, because an instance $\varphi(x,b)$ which divides over $A$ may no longer divide over $A$ after expanding the language. The same goes for characterizing (non)-stability by the order property, and many other properties in model theory.]

Now we carry out the proof above in $T^+$. We have an $L$-formula $\varphi(x,y)$ with the tree property, so there is a $\varphi$-$k$-dividing sequence $(\varphi(x,b_\alpha))_{\alpha<\kappa^+}$. Let $M = \langle \{b_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa^+\}\rangle$, the substructure of the monster generated by all the parameters in the sequence. Since $T^+$ has Skolem functions, $M\models T^+$. Similarly, for all $\beta<\kappa^+$, if we define $M_\beta = \langle \{b_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\}\rangle$, then $M_\beta\models T^+$. Note that $M = \bigcup_{\beta<\kappa^+} M_\beta$.

By the definition of dividing sequence, $\{\varphi(x,b_\alpha)\mid \alpha<\kappa^+\}$ is consistent, so we can take $p\in S(M)$ to be any completion of this partial type. Now for any $X\subseteq M$ with $|X|\leq \kappa$, since $\kappa^+$ is regular there is some $\beta<\kappa^+$ such that $X\subseteq M_\beta$. By the definition of dividing sequence, $\varphi(x,b_\beta)\in p$ divides over $\{b_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\}$, so it divides over $M_\beta$ (if a formula divides over $A$, then it also divides over $\langle A \rangle$) and hence over $X$, so $p$ divides over $X$.

It remains to show that the conclusion is preserved when we take the reduct back to $L$. The key thing to check is that if an $L$-formula divides over $X$ in $\mathfrak{C}^+$, then it divides over $X$ in $\mathfrak{C}$.

Comment: Ahh, that's a very very nice argument, thank you; the use of Skolem functions for this purpose is a really good trick to remember for the future. Just to make sure, your last sentence doesn't rely on anything special about $\mathfrak{C}^+$, right? For any expansion $L\subseteq L^*$, if two tuples have the same $L^*$-type over $X$, then they will in particular have the same $L$-type over $X$, so the same witnesses of dividing will work in the reduct.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yep, that's correct. Slogan: "Dividing is preserved under reduct (as long as the dividing formula is contained in the reduct language), but not necessarily under expansion."