# Equivalence between the $k$-Tree Property and the 2-Tree Property.

Tags: logic, model-theory

A definition of the Tree Property can be found in [The "tree property" and dividing types](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948865/the-tree-property-and-dividing-types).

In Shelah's Classification theory there is a proof of the equivalence between the $k$-Tree Property and the 2-Tree Property but I find it a bit convoluted. I remember reading somewhere a direct proof of this fact but I can't find it or prove it myself.

The idea I was trying is to start with a witness for the $k$-TP (i.e., some formula $\varphi$ and some tree $(a_\eta)_{\eta\in 2^{<\omega}})$ and modify it somehow, for example changing $\varphi$ for a conjunction of $k-2$ instances of $\varphi$. This guarantees the 2-inconsistent condition but we may loose consistency over any branch.

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: The proof is not at all easy! Given $\varphi$ with $k$-TP you will indeed get a conjunction of $\varphi$ that has $2$-TP, but not necessarily $k-2$ conjuncts. Shelah does indeed prove this in Theorem III.7.7 of classification theory, and I'm not aware of a (substantially) simpler proof.